# Delete a part from ogg file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I use this command to crop audio files:

```
ffmpeg -ss 50 -i "input.ogg" -acodec copy -y -t 100 "output.ogg"
```

This works fine. But now, I'd like to delete a section from an audio file - preferably without recompressing it.

Example: input.ogg has duration 60sec, delete section [10s:20s] => output.ogg has then duration 50sec and includes section [0:10s] and [20s:60s] from input.ogg.

Is it possible with one command or do I have to split the file into two and then join it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that SoX can do it with the trim command, but only with recompressing the file.